# dotnet new console fails to create when being built within a mapped directory docker container

Tags: .net, docker

I'm starting begin dockerizing more and more of my school work. I've had no issue with python projects however a simple C# project is giving me some headache. All I want to do right now is create a new hello world console project and run it with a mapped directory.

This is the docker command that I've been using to run a container:

`C:\Documents\test>docker run --expose=89 -p 8888:89 -v C:\Documents\test:\test --rm --name csharp_attempt -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:5.0`

I can build create a simple hello world project within the root container by simply creating a new directory and executing:

`dotnet new console`
The project will build and I can see hello world works fine.

However if cd into "\test" and try and create a new console the build fails even though the .csproj file is created I still get an MSB1009 error, here is my console output:

```
root@488f9a396b91:/# ls
'\test'   bin   boot   dev   etc   home   lib   lib64   media   mnt   opt   proc   root   run   sbin   srv   sys   tmp   usr   var
root@488f9a396b91:/# cd "\\test"/
root@488f9a396b91:/\test# ls
root@488f9a396b91:/\test# dotnet new console
Getting ready...
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on /\test/\test.csproj...
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: //test//test.csproj
Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

Comment: Run 'dotnet restore'

Comment: It looks like there is some sort of pathing issue: ```root@488f9a396b91:/\test# dotnet restore
/test/test.csproj : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path '/test/test.csproj'. [//test//test.csproj]
root@488f9a396b91:/\test# ls
 Program.cs  '\test.csproj' ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're targeting Linux containers, I would recommend not using `\test` as your mapped directory in the container. That's actually creating a directory in your container with the backslash in the name. I don't think that's your intent here. By doing it that way, it's messing up the filename generation of the `dotnet new console` command, creating a project file with the name `'\test.csproj'` (all those characters are part of the filename, not the path). The dotnet CLI is not recognizing that as being a project file because it doesn't end in `.csproj`, it ends in `.csproj'`.

The recommendation would be to use the forward slash. This would be the recommended command:

```
docker run --expose=89 -p 8888:89 -v C:\Documents\test:/test --rm --name csharp_attempt -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:5.0
```

This will allow you to run the following commands in the container:

```
root@d0d52159a266:/# cd test
root@d0d52159a266:/test# dotnet new console
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on /test/test.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /test/test.csproj (in 80 ms).
Restore succeeded.
```

Comment: So much trouble caused by a simple slash!